# Проблема с telegram ботом

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Начал писать telegram бота на python с помощью библиотеки telebot. Проблема такая: не получается отправить файл pdf по ID в ответ на нажатие кнопки. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot= telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Да',callback_data='next'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет {message.from_user.username}', reply_markup=markup)
        
    
@bot.message_handler()
def info(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Да',callback_data='next'))
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет {message.from_user.username}', reply_markup=markup)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback(callback):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Получить',callback_data='yes'))
    if (callback.data == 'next'):
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Отлично!.", reply_markup=markup)
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.calback.data)
def echo_all(callback):
    if (callback.data == 'yes'):
     file ='ID ФАЙЛА'
    bot.send_document(callback.message.chat.id, file)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Для начала сюда - [ask]